# Сортировка вектор из пары строковых значений

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, stl

Есть вектор вида vector<pair<string, string>>, необходимо отсортировать его по первому строковому значение, конкретно здесь это фамилия, как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
vector<pair<string, string>> v;
sort(v.begin(),v.end(),[](const pair<string, string>& a, const pair<string, string>& b)
     { return a.first < b.first; });
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо, работает, сейчас начну разбираться

Comment: Лямбда тут лишняя, она может даже ухудшить ситуацию.

Comment: @Mikhailo Да, как-то это забывается :( Вы правы. Единственное оправдание - что это демонстрация *метода*..

Answer (score 1):

Просто сортировать:

```
vector<pair<string, string>> v;
sort(v.begin(),v.end());
```

Все почему-то забывают, что `pair` сравнивается по умолчанию по первому, а потом по второму полю.

Вот [доказательство](https://ideone.com/o3S6UN).

Comment: Так при совпадении фамилий он начнет сравнивать по второму полю и получится непонятно что.

Comment: как это "непонятно что", получится "стабильная, предсказуемая сортировка"

Comment: @gbg Будет детерминированная сортировка. Сортировка с лямбдой оставит второе поле не рассмотренным, так что при совпадении фамилий как раз может быть что угодно. А при вот такой сортировке будет сортировка по второму полю (имени, например).

Comment: @KoVadim - ценой бессмысленных сравнений? У автора не написано, что второе поле должно принимать участие в сортировке.

Comment: Ох уже эти оптимизаторы...